# string in Ruby on rails questions: 1. <code> 2. how to recognize "put"?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently developing web application with Ruby on rails.

When I command

```
<h4>wow this is a good webpage <code>loving each other</code> good good</h3>
```

, "loving each other" part are highlighted ( And I meant it because I learned this code can work through getbootstrap! )  : "code" "code" <---- in Stackoverflow page code code command is working so I put this here intentionally in a wrong way.

I wanted to make a specific string data look like that. In the application, I get the string data  from

```
<textarea class = "form-control" name="input"></textarea>
```

But when I displayed it in the html, `<code>` part was not recognized as a sort of code but a just string. Partially it seems it does make sense but not fully understood. How can I turn this type of information into a formatted version ( meaning some part is highlighted! )

Second question is that, the string data got from `<textarea>` has "entering actions" meaning, the user clicks the "enter" a couple of times. When I display this information (for instance, @a = User.information, <- where User.information has a couple of sentences that are equal to the  information ), the enters don't appear and all sentences look messy :(

I think there is for sure a way to do it properly!!!
Looking forward to hearing opinion from the experts!

Comment: You need to html_safe or raw it so it isn't escaped.

Comment: And for the line breaks, prior to rendering, replace all "\n" with "<br/>"

Comment: Also, html attributes need to have this syntax:  `class="form-control"`, ie no spaces.

Comment: The problem is, I'm not the one who can add "\n" in the information. The information I get is what other people entered in the <textarea>. Would you have any idea Sergio? Need your help!

Comment: Hi Max thanks for your comment! I put the sentence a bit wrong. You're right and that's not what bothered me. Do you have any suggestion I can interpret what other people typed via textarea? :) Need your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While rendering you should do something like this:

```
"<h4>wow this is a good webpage <code>loving each other</code> good good</h3>".gsub('\n','<br/>).html_safe
```

Comment: Wow it works! So I put the information to my variable with what you suggested me and when I display via the html file, it appears that the command works! Thanks a lot! Appreciate it!!

Comment: @SungpahLee : You can accept the answer if it worked for you.